# Python Anagrams in empty list

Tags: python, dictionary, anagram

Question: Write a program which initializes an empty list and then prompts the user for a single word and keeps prompting for single words, adding each word to the list, until the user enters a single period character '.' Then print all pairs of words which are anagrams. Comparisons should be case insensitive. - Can use dictionary to simply, but not required. Can define functions as seen fit.

I have tried several versions of the code below and I just can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help by pointing me in the right direction/giving me an example code that is similar? I'm just so stuck.

```
def areAnagrams(inputList):
    """Return inputList if words are anagrams, False otherwise"""
    inputList = sorted(inputList.lower())
    return inputList

inputList = raw_input ("Enter a word period to end: ") 
list = []
while inputList != '.':
    anagram = inputList
    list.append(anagram)
    inputList = raw_input("Enter a word (period to end): ")


print "Anagrams:", areAnagrams(inputList)
```

Comment: You've not actually implemented any code that would find anagrams.  All your `areAnagrams` method does is return the input list sorted.  Are you expecting somebody to do your homework for you?

Comment: why are you sorting the list?

Comment: Bad variable naming maybe ... here you append data to a variable named "list" and you're calling your function on a variable called "inputList", at this point this variable always contains a '.'.

Comment: Nope, I'm not expecting anything. Just got lost in this particular problem. I created this off of an example problem for anagrams (where two words were inputed than sorted) that we had in class. Wanted to know if I was even close to being on the right track and I'm not.

Comment: "Then print all pairs of words which are anagrams." First hint: if you expect your function `areAnagrams` to be able to tell you if a pair of words are anagrams, you're going to have to give it two separate words when you call it.

Comment: You should use dictionary for this exercise. Make sorted tuple of a word your keys, and a list of possible anagrams your values.

Answer (score 1):

Just focussing on the part where you check whether two words are anagrams, your function needs to check whether both words are the same length, and contain all the same letters. So you could do:

```
def areAnagrams(word1, word2):
    if len(word1) == len(word2):
        word1Letters = sorted(list(word1))
        word2Letters = sorted(list(word2))
        if word1Letters == word2Letters:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else: 
        return False
```

Comment: this code is way more complicated than it should be, just do `def areAnagrams(w1, w2): return sorted(list(w1)) == sorted(list(w2))`

Comment: @Doboy Yeah, you're probably right. The simpler version would only fail in the edge case where one of the words contains an extra letter that comes later in the alphabet than all others (eg. 'rap', 'prat'), and that's assuming that the length constraint applies.